# How to make sure every event only can be view by role_id (only super admin can see all the list) in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My data can be seen in this image from CodeIgniter [image: event list].

[this one is event controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B17ve.png)

[this one is event model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hntlB.png)

I want to make sure every event only can be viewed by role id. I tried to change the controller Event.php:

```php
public function index($school_id = null, $id = null, $role_id=null) {
     
        check_permission(VIEW);

        

        $this->data['events'] = $this->event->get_event_list($school_id, $role_id);
        $this->data['roles'] = $this->event->get_list('roles', array('status' => 1), '', '', 'id','ASC');
        $this->data['filter_school_id'] = $school_id;
        $this->data['schools'] = $this->schools;
       
        $this->data['list'] = TRUE;
        $this->layout->title($this->lang->line('manage_event') . ' | ' . SMS);
        $this->layout->view('event/index', $this->data);
    }
```

I also try to change the event_model.php:

```
public function get_event_list($school_id = null, $role_id=null) {
        
        $this->db->select('E.*, S.school_name, R.name');
        $this->db->from('events AS E');
        $this->db->join('roles AS R', 'R.id = E.role_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('schools AS S', 'S.id = E.school_id', 'left');
        
        if($this->session->userdata('role_id') != SUPER_ADMIN){
            $this->db->where('E.school_id', $this->session->userdata('school_id'));
            $this->db->where('R.role_id', $this->session->userdata('role_id'));
        }
        
        if($this->session->userdata('role_id') == SUPER_ADMIN && $school_id){
            $this->db->where('E.school_id', $school_id);
        }
        $this->db->where('S.status', 1);
        $this->db->order_by('E.id', 'DESC');
        
        return $this->db->get()->result();
        
    }
```

Comment: HI @NajwaIsmail welcome to Stack Overflow.   Generally it's recommended to put text snippets rather than screenshots.  Also please update your post to include what about what you tried that isn't working / what you are confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know how to do it so I just change a few on coding on event model:

```
 public function get_event_list($school_id = null, $role_id ){
  
    $this->db->select('E.*, S.school_name, R.name');
    $this->db->from('events AS E');
    $this->db->join('roles AS R', 'R.id = E.role_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('schools AS S', 'S.id = E.school_id', 'left');
    
    if($this->session->userdata('role_id') != SUPER_ADMIN){
        $this->db->where('E.school_id', $this->session->userdata('school_id'));
        $this->db->where('E.role_id', $this->session->userdata('role_id'));
        
    }
    
    if($this->session->userdata('role_id') == SUPER_ADMIN && $school_id){
        $this->db->where('E.school_id', $school_id);
    }
    $this->db->where('S.status', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('E.id', 'DESC');
    
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```

And this one is for event controller:

public function index($school_id = null, $id = null, $role_id=null) {

```
    check_permission(VIEW);

    $this->data['school'] = array();
    $school_id = $this->session->userdata('school_id');
    $class_id = $this->session->userdata('class_id');
    $role_id = $this->session->userdata('role_id');
    

    $this->data['events'] = $this->event->get_event_list($school_id, $role_id);
    $this->data['roles'] = $this->event->get_list('roles', array('status' => 1,), '', '', 'id', 'ASC');
    $this->data['filter_school_id'] = $school_id;
    $this->data['schools'] = $this->schools;
   
    $this->data['list'] = TRUE;
    $this->layout->title($this->lang->line('manage_event') . ' | ' . SMS);
    $this->layout->view('event/index', $this->data);
}
```